# Firefox making empty div have height when overflow scroll

Tags: css, firefox

The following is an empty div in chrome and safari:

```
<div style="overflow: scroll; position: relative;"></div>
```

But in firefox leads to a div that is 15px high. If I remove the overflow, it goes back down to 0 (just as in chrome/safari). Am I missing something? Is there a way to make it be 0 height in firefox without removing the overflow property?

Comment: Are you changing the height dynamically? You can set `height:0px`. Although I don't know the technical reasons of why Firefox does that. It's like Firefox is just showing some default scroll bars.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the context is dynamic.

Comment: Then it shouldn't be a problem, I think. If you set the `height` to `0` initially you can later change it dynamically. Is that the approach you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this would solve your problem:

```
<div class="scrollable"></div>
```

CSS

```
.scrollable{
    overflow:scroll;
    position:relative;
}
.scrollable:empty{
    height:0;
}
```

Comment: Really interesting solution. I didn't know about that selector.

Comment: Agreed, never heard of it and it has [good browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aempty#Browser_compatibility).